# using DCT for embeding watermark

Tags: opencv, watermark, dct

I wrote down an openCV code .I tried to embed a 64X64 pix watermark image in a 512X512 image.
my code has 5 parts:

1. reading two pictures( watermark and original image that I want to
   embed watermark in it)
2. resize 2 readed images to specified size.(64X64 for watermark image
   and 512X512 for original image)
3. devide original resized image to 8X8 blocks and transform them with
   DCT.
4. embedding each pixel of watermark in each block of original image.
5. applying inverse DCT on each block.

I have this problem that all of three imshows have same results.
thank you for your help :)

here is my code :

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

int index=0;
int iindex=0;
vector<Mat> blocks(4096);


/////////////Part1:reading images


Mat originalImage;     
originalImage = imread("C:\\MGC.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);   
Mat watermarkImage;  
watermarkImage = imread("C:\\ivp_lg.bmp" , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

/// show original image
namedWindow("Original");
int x = 0; int y = 0;
moveWindow("Original", x, y);
imshow("Original", originalImage);
x += 100; y += 100;


//////Part 2:Leave originals alone, work on a copys. resize readed images 


Mat dctImage = originalImage.clone();
Mat wmrk = watermarkImage.clone();
Mat tmp1(512, 512, CV_8UC1);
Mat tmp2(64, 64, CV_8UC1);
resize(dctImage, dctImage, tmp1.size());
resize(wmrk, wmrk , tmp2.size());


/////Part 3:break dctImage into 8X8 blocks and applying DCT on each block


for (int i = 0; i < 512; i += 8)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 512; j+= 8)
    {
        Mat block = dctImage(Rect(i, j, 8, 8)); 
        block.convertTo(block,  CV_32FC1); 
        dct(block,blocks[index]);
        blocks[index].convertTo(blocks[index], CV_8UC1);
        index++;

    }
}

/// show transformed image
namedWindow("TransformedImage");
moveWindow("TransformedImage", x, y);
imshow("TransformedImage",dctImage );
x += 100; y += 100;


//////Part 4: embeding watermark. if corresponding pixel of watermark was 255 then element (5,5) in the block increase 200 otherwise do nothing


for(int idx=0 ; idx<4096 ; idx++)
{
    int i=idx/64;
    int j=idx%64;
    float elem=(float) wmrk.at<uchar>(i,j);
    if (elem>=128)
        {

            float tmp=(float) blocks[idx].at<uchar>(5,5);
            float temp=tmp +200;
            uchar ch=(uchar) temp;
            blocks[idx].at<uchar>(5,5)=ch;
        }
}


//////Part 5:applying iDCT on each block    


for (int i = 0; i < 512; i += 8)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 512; j+= 8)
    {
        Mat block = dctImage(Rect(i, j, 8, 8)); 
        block.convertTo(block,  CV_32FC1); 
        idct(block,blocks[iindex]);
        blocks[iindex].convertTo(blocks[iindex], CV_8UC1);
        iindex++;

    }
}

/// show watermarked image
namedWindow("WatermarkedImage");
moveWindow("WatermarkedImage", x, y);
imshow("WatermarkedImage",dctImage );



cvWaitKey(80000);

destroyAllWindows();

return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you are able to work on digital watermarking by using another method of DCT, I can help you via MATLAB to use a robust watermarking method which is based on Quantization Index Modulation (QIM). You can search for it if you are interested..

Comment: @Christina : thank you for your proposal .I'm intrested in digital watermarking but I'm very intrested in C++ programming also and exactly becuse of this I want to implement watermarking by openCV library of C++ programming.

Answer (score -1):

@N_Kh As far as I have seen ur code in hurry, You are executing IMSHOW Command over the Matrix dctImage while you are performing operation on different Matrix and vector Block and Blocks respectively.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11928032)

Comment: @MarounMaroun I think this is the answer to his question that why is he getting same image after the execution of IMSHOW command.
He didnt ask for any code, I Believe..!!